# Qwebview, how to resize it with window/

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I've got an QWebView object inside my project and i want it to resize whenever i am resizing a main window. How to achieve that?
http://pastebin.com/3wcUygvb <- That's the ui code/

Comment: I don't think I follow. Does it *not* resize with the window?

Comment: No, it does not resizing when i resize window. QWebView widget stays as it was at launch time.

Comment: Ah, OK. I see the problem now. Can you post the `.ui` file? You probably didn't put things into layouts properly. But editing the generated `.py` is kind of pointless. Or I can rewrite this with a non-Designer way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've put all your widgets in layouts, but you haven't set a layout on the main form.

In Qt Designer, right-click on a blank area of the form and select `Layout/Layout in a Grid`.

Then save and re-compile with `pyuic4`.